# Show Canvas by trigger in Unity3d

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine, collision

I have a scene with two cubes, and canvas. One cube falls onto another. Canvas appearing must be triggered by collision. It's does not working. Where's the problem?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EverythingInside : MonoBehaviour
{

public Canvas GUICanvas;
void Start()
{
}
void OnGUI()
{
    GUICanvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "FallingCube")
    {
        OnGUI();
    }
}
void Update()
{
}

}
```

Comment: What are you doing? Calling `OnGUI();` from another function. `OnGUI();` is callback function. You are not suppose to call it by any means. Mixing OnGUI(); with Canvas? You question is confusing in different levels. You want cube to collide with Canvas? Start here http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials Understand how to use the UI and how physics work in Unity.

Comment: Errm... That's what happens when 3d artist tries to be programmer. 
_>>You want cube to collide with Canvas?_
Nope, one cube hits another, and their collision must to trigger canvas appearing.
Surely, I'm going to read those tutorials, but I hope someone can show me how to fix this crap.

Comment: Good for you. The code in your question made me cringe and your comment is more understandable than your question. Maybe the way you phrased it. Make sure to visit those links in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code below inside your `EverythingInside` script. Make sure `Collider` and `Rigidbody` are attached to both cubes. Also make sure to drag your Canvas from the Editor to the GUICanvas slot.

```
public Canvas GUICanvas;

void Start()
{

}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("FallingCube"))
    {
        GUICanvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}

void Update()
{

}
```

[Unity Physics tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics).

[Unity UI Tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

[Unity Scripting Tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting).

Comment: Thanks, but it's doesn't not want to work. I'm dont sure what am I doing wrong. It's about both answers.

Comment: It's so simple, but it's not working. Amusing, but kinda piss me off. I would be grateful if someone checks my project. [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s26pxnvkn5br5b2/ForStackoverflow.rar?dl=0)

Comment: @user3795090 

1.Google how to create tag in unity.

2.You have to create a tag called **FallingCube**.

3. You must change the tag of the falling cube tag to be **FallingCube**. 

4.Remove that Script from the Canvas and attach it to both cubes. For OnCollisionEnter, it has to be attached to those objects that will collide. I don't even know why you attached this to the Canvas.

Comment: 5. Finally, watch those videos before making more posts. It might take days, weeks or months but when you are done, you won't be asking such questions. I will ignore your next comment if it doesn't work. You have to help yourself. Here is the fixed version. http://wikisend.com/download/164498/package.unitypackage

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that OnGUI() as a function is called once every frame in Unity, regardless of whether or not you call it manually. Also, OnGUI is reserved for doing things like rendering simple buttons and text directly to the screen, it doesn't perform any actual logic.

All you have to do to make this work is just replace where you've called OnGui() with GUICanvas.gameObject.SetActive(true)
and get rid of the other functions.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EverythingInside : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas GUICanvas;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "FallingCube")
        {
            GUICanvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

That right there is literally all you need to make it work. Bear in mind that if you change it later on to be a trigger instead of two colliding cubes you will need to replave OnCollisionEnter with OnTriggerEnter.

Comment: So what's the difference between the code in your  and my answer? Other than one of them allocate memory each time there is a collision.